# Read mode on MongoId 6.3.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I've been using the option .with(read: {mode: :secondary}) on Mongoid 5, but now I upgraded Mongoid to 6.3 and I'm getting a LocalJumpError (no block given (yield))
Any idea on how can I do a specific query to a secondary node?

Comment: Why were you using that mode? I think it's a fair thing to ask since if you do not understand the current error then you probably did not understand all the consequences of preferring reads from a secondary node in the first place. Unless you actually understand all of those consequences then your application should prefer **primary** reads **always**. Doing anything else is likely to lead to data inconsistencies.

Comment: Hi, I'm using it to perform some slow queries that I don't need to perform on the primary because I could handle some delay on the sync and don't want them to overload my primary. I understand the consequences.

Answer (score 1):

Mongoid 6 and 7 require that `#with` is passed a block, so that the created persistence context can be cleaned up in a timely manner.

https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/6.4/tutorials/mongoid-persistence/#runtime-persistence-options

```
model.with(collection: "artists") do |model_with_new_persistence_context|
  # ...
end
```